# How to find barcodes of a PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8, barcode, barcode-scanner

I started searching how to create a Windows Phone 8 app to recognize barcodes inside a PDF document.

My best guest is to following the process below:

1. Find a lib to split PDF documents into image streams (one per page).
2. Find a lib to recognize if there is a barcode in the image stream:

   2.1. Try to recognize barcode in each portion of the image, i. e.:

   try #1 (from y = 0, x = 0 to y = 100, x = 100);

   try #2 (from y = 100, x = 0 to y = 200, x = 100);

   try #3 (from y = 200, x = 0 to y = 300, x = 100);

   and so on.

I'm wondering if this is the best approach to accomplish barcode recognition in a PDF document using WP8.

Another concern is about whether this process when executed by a not so good device will present an acceptable performance.

Someone already did that? Any advice?

**UPDATE**

I want to scan ITF barcodes, i. e., I need to scan the barcode in this image:
[image]

I'm trying to start achieving the scanning barcodes from a Image, but I'm not getting success. Below is my first try:

```
        //get the assets folder for the app
        StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");

        BitmapSource bitmapSource = await GetBitmapImage(folder, "Barcode.png");
        WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapSource);

        var rgb = new RGBLuminanceSource(writeableBitmap.ToByteArray(), writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight);
        var hybrid = new HybridBinarizer(rgb);
        BinaryBitmap binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(hybrid);

        Reader reader = new ITFReader();

        try
        {
            Result result = reader.decode(binBitmap);
            if (result != null)
            {
                this.textBlock.Text = result.Text;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.textBlock.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Unfortunately, my text box is being filled up with this Exception:

```
        Exception of type 'com.google.zxing.ReaderException' was thrown.
```

I'm using this "lib": https://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/

Comment: _"Another concern is about whether this process when **executed by a not so good device** will present an **acceptable performance**"_ - probably could apply to anything if you don't define what a _not so good device_ is.  What is a good device?  Also will depend on what _"lib"_ you choose to use

Comment: Duncan, you are correct in your comment. What I meant is that I do not have any experience in recognizing barcode and I can not guess if a simple recognition, following the process explained, in a Lumia 930, for example, will took 2 seconds (acceptable) or 20 seconds (unacceptable). Directly to the point, I need some advices about how to accomplish my task in a acceptable performance.

Comment: Thanks.  Consider editing your answer to include the ideal time requirements

Comment: The common barcode reader libs usually do integrate a barcode finding functionality. So you do not need step 2.1 . However, if you would tell us the type of barcode you are looking for and provide an example image/pdf we would not have to dust of the crystal ball.

Comment: ToblTobs, I need to scan ITF barcodes, like the barcode in the image I uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this concept actually works.

- Read the `PDF` as `Image`
- after that use any external Library to detect `Barcodes` from image. (There are many libraries available to do so)

And for another concern that you mentioned regarding performance of Low-End devices, it depends on many things.

- First of all it depends on the library that you use to convert `PDF` to `Image`
- then library that you use to detect `Barcode` from `Image`.

though there is no certainity for Time Complexity in this Task, what i think is it will not take much time then required..! It's a general process, so you can go with the scenario above.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Langalia, I got some errors while trying the second step, could you help me: Details are in my update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help you to implement the part 1 of the solution, render PDF to image:
[this blog post shows how to do it on windows phone](http://blog.apitron.com/2013/08/windows-phone-store-application-convert-pdf-to-image-.net.html) and this lib can be used to convert PDFs to images in universal windows store apps as well as xamarin apps. I personally use it in my projects and because it offers same API for all platforms it fits incredibly well.